# Object constructor

Tags: qt, constructor, qml

I am looking for any documentation or help for the following issue:

I want to be able to call an "Object Constructor" in my .qml files.
To be a bit more clear, I would like to find a way to not duplicate the implementation of an object in QML. For example:
Take this basic rectangle,

```
Rectangle {
    id : rect1
    width: 100
    height: 100
    color: "red"
    radius: 10
}
```

Imagine I have 30 of them to build in my .qml page. I would prefer to not duplicate the code and just call a constructor like:

```
rectangleConstructor(string id, int w, int h, string c, int r)
{
Rectangle {
        id : id
        width: w
        height: h
        color: c
        radius: r
    }
```

And just call this constructor 30 times with the right value.
Like:

```
rectangleConstructor(rect1, 100, 40, "white", 10);
rectangleConstructor(rect2, 150, 40, "black", 10);
rectangleConstructor(rect3, 200, 40, "white", 10);
```

Is it possible in QML? I didn't find any documentation or example on this.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html might be useful, especially you can use `object createObject(QtObject parent, object properties)` to set properties for the dynamically created object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start out by directly answering your question, but then I'll give you what I think is a better alternative.

You can create a function to construct an object dynamically. It would look something like this:

```
Window {
    id: parentWindow

    Component {
        id: someComponent
        Rectangle {
        }
    }

    function rectangleConstructor(int w, int h, string c, int r) {
        someComponent.createObject(parentWindow, { width: w, height: h, color: c, radius: r})
    }

    Component.onCompleted:
    {
        var rect1 = rectangleConstructor(100, 40, "white", 10);
        var rect2 = rectangleConstructor(150, 40, "black", 10);
        var rect3 = rectangleConstructor(200, 40, "white", 10);
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that you have to call that function from another javascript function/expression. Function calls can't just be loose within QML. That's why my example calls it from within Component.onCompleted. That might be ok for your application. It depends. It affects the timing of when those objects will be available.

A better way is to avoid old paradigms and use a more QML-style approach. You can avoid duplicated code by using a Repeater with a model of some type. The model could even be defined in C++ code, if you want.

```
ListModel {
    id: rectModel
    ListElement { w: 100, h: 40, c: "white", r: 10 }
    ListElement { w: 150, h: 40, c: "black", r: 10 }
    ListElement { w: 200, h: 40, c: "white", r: 10 }
}

Repeater {
    model: rectModel
    Rectangle {
        width: w
        height: h
        color: c
        radius: r
    }
}
```